# django: noob question about querying the models

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following tables:

```
class SchoolClass(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    class_name = models.TextField()
    level = models.IntegerField()
    taught_by = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name="taught_by",through='TeachSubject')
    attended_by = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='attended_by')

class ConsentFormTemplate(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    body = models.TextField()
    teacher_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
    consent_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "consent_form_template"

class ConsentForm(models.Model):
    student_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
    remarks = models.TextField()
    #class_id = models.ForeignKey(SchoolClass)

    reply = models.NullBooleanField()
    parents_remark = models.TextField()
    tpl = models.ForeignKey(ConsentFormTemplate)
    acknowledged_by = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='acknowledged_by',null=True,blank=True)
    acknowledged_on = models.DateField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add=True,null=True)
    date_sent = models.DateField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add =True)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('tpl_id','studentId')

    class Meta:
        db_table = "consent_form"
```

Given the pk of the consentformtemplate, how can i construct my ORM query such that my results are as such:

```
first_name(student) | class_name
```

Comment: Which first_name do you want? A teacher's? A student's? Both for each class?

Comment: @arie, sorry arie i edited my question its student's

Comment: Best bet is to refactor your code. You've got some serious logic problems that will continually be a source of frustration. Things like `student_id` should just be `student` since it's a foreign key. Otherwise, you'll end up with lookups that include stuff like `student_id__id` which doesn't make any sense. Related names are also a problem: `related_name` should specify the reverse relationship. Looking up `SchoolClass` objects through teacher `User` objects via `taught_by` is illogical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
consentformtemplate=ConsentFormTemplate.objects.get(pk=consentformtemplate_pk)

consents = ConsentForm.objects.filter(tpl=consentformtemplate).select_related()

for consent in consents:
    print "%s | %s" % (consent.student_id.first_name, consent.class_id.class_name)
```